# Avoiding burnout in long projects

Tags: sprint, human-resources, deadline

When managing large projects with hard deadlines 2-6 months away, are there known methods of reducing team burnout?

Projects of the type I'm referring to are sometimes termed "death marches" - though they are ultimately successful they have a set, very tight deadline set long in advance. Due to the large scope of these projects and their components as well as the dependencies between components, timing is risky and bound to underestimate. This inevitably leads to prolonged periods of work under stress and as a consequence, overworked and burned out employees.

Given that one is assigned to manage such a project, what are some project management methodologies and human elements that can make the development more sustainable?

Comment: 2-6 months of a deadline is nothing. In the health sector, there are projects with deadlines of 40 years.

Comment: "If I completely botch the project planning and mistreat my team horribly, how can I do this in a nice way?". There is no answer. The answer is: do a better job and don't mess up the project in the first place.

Comment: @nvoigt - As mentioned, some sectors don't leave you with a choice as to schedule.

Comment: No, some sectors have fixed external dealines (for example new laws taking effect). But it is always your choice what team works on that, how that team is staffed and skilled. If the deadline is "tight" and "risky", that is on you for understaffing or underskilling your team, in other words, a project management failure.

Comment: @nvoigt - Perhaps, but reality doesn't always leave you in a position where you have the finances, human talent or experience needed to execute with less risk.

Comment: Far too broad a question. Please revise to specifics.  The only answer at this breadth is "show empathy and respect". Negotiate the iron triangle with management.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @ nbubis - do your schedule with team. Present it. Refuse to budge until customer expectation yields to reality. If they refuse to resource you, then they are aware a long way out that the deadline will be missed. If they acknowledge and up-resource, then take it from there. You don't try and placate a toddler that wants to put their hand in the fire - so why placate a customer that has a similar level of ignorance toward self-harm? To do so is only doing both parties a disservice.

Answer (score 1):

Sellers of services face this situation quite often, I find. It is a choice to continue working in that environment but, when facing unemployment, that choice is quite priviledged.

No matter the deadline, the work will take as long as it will take. What will happen is you will accrue unfavorable variances in both schedule, cost, and quality, and the wrath you will face from those sponsoring the work will grow. As the PM, you need to shield your team from that wrath. Because of an unrealistic performance baseline, it'll appear they are "under performing" but in reality they are likely performing as reasonably expected or maybe even over performing.

Without passion, you need to report factually where you are and where you are headed. People are the first to get blamed and the easiest to blame so you are going to get a ton of heat. You need to absorb that heat and keep it away from your team. Then keep going and make sure you team has what it needs, including rest. (It'll feel like they are going to fire you but, in reality, they likely know they gave you unrealistic and unreasonable constraints and changing you out will almost certainly make things work. They'll likely just keep screaming.)

As an aside, accruing unfavorable cost variances early, ie, up staffing to help with the work and schedule, is less expensive than recovery near the end. Very hard to do if you have to get approvals but keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of burnout is the lack of a **fine-grained motivational system**. Define smaller deliverables for each team member, make sure they are achievable, reward for getting them on time, and punish for missing them. In other words, let people work for themselves and their own motivation, instead of a large project goal, which, let's face it, nobody really cares about.

Answer (score 1):

> When managing large projects with hard deadlines 2-6 months away, are there known methods of reducing team burnout?

Don't let your project get into a stage where it is a death march.

When first starting on the project, make an estimate with the team to see if the timeline is at all feasible with the current team. If you are going to miss the deadline even if everything works and there are no unexpected hiccups, communicate that as early and clearly as possible to your stakeholders and management. If they are worth their pay, the sooner they know about the inherent inability to meet the deadline, the more they can do to help you.

Secondly, do risk management: Try to get as clear a picture as you can of the risks that exist for the project and how and how much they affect schedule, cost, etc.

Once you have an overview of the risks, find ways to mitigate their impact or chance. The sooner a mitigation action is effective, the better it is.

If a major risk is that the parts don't work together correctly when they finally come together at the end of the project, then a mitigation would be to create earlier and more frequent integration points, possibly with just partial functionality implemented.

The aim of this risk management is to know as soon as possible when something happened that threatens you to miss the deadline and by how much. Then you can involve your stakeholders and management in creating a plan that works better than "just work harder".

Answer (score 0):

It can be difficult to manage huge projects with strict deadlines, especially when it comes to avoiding team burnout. The Agile management project management techniques can increase the sustainability of the development

Agile project management techniques: Agile project management techniques like Scrum or Kanban can help to divide the project down into smaller, more manageable tasks that can be finished in fewer iterations. By setting up frequent checkpoints for progress and allowing for flexibility in the project plan, this can help to prevent burnout.

Comment: Why and how? Any evidence?